# Saving date array to database drupal

Tags: arrays, date, drupal

How can i save date array to database?

the code belove creates a form for date

```
$form['date_time'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Date'),
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#description' => t('Please enter the date.'),

);
```

User then selects the month,day,year.

How can i convert it so that i can save it to database?

```
function repman_form_submit($form, &$form_state){


drupal_set_message($form_state['values']['date_time']);
```

I am just using the drupal_set_message to view the output. And i get array.

**UPDATE:**

Done it using this

```
            'date_month'=> $form_state['values']['date_time']['month'],
    'date_day' => $form_state['values']['date_time']['day'],
    'date_year'=> $form_state['values']['date_time']['year'],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert the date to ATOM or a unix timestamp:

```
// Dates are stored in ATOM format. 1969-12-31T19:33:33-05:00
$value = date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y));

// Convert to unix time
$value = date('U', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y));
```

I believe sql datetime uses ATOM but you can also stor it as a unix time stamp if you want to just stor it as an integer value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i just broke it into 3 peaces then saved them into the database.